# Discord py music from yt queue link

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl

I'm currently using ytdl and ffmpeg to run music with my discord bot...but I cant add queue from youtube queue links..Is there any way to add queue from youtube queue links??..and also a shuffle command would be also great..

Answer (score 1):

For a basic music bot, visit [the example from the official discord.py github page](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py).